# Hosted Service/Backgroundservice being stopped for .Net Core Hosted in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-appservice, asp.net-core-hosted-services

Hi I am facing this problem for quite some days. Hope I can find some solution here.

I am having a dotnet core application where I have implemented HostingService to pickup some records from database and push it to quartz trigger.

Following works fine in IIS but when deployed to Azure HostingService is been run for few iterations and there's no logs after some time.

I have been using  the sample from this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/).

My Execute will look something like this

```
Execute:
{
   for(;true;)
   {
      writelog()
      List data = getfromdb();
      foreach(var d in data )
      {
        if(checklogic)
        {
          pushtoquartz(d)
        }
      }
   }
}
```

There's so many jobs I need to fire at same time like 10.00 AM Daily this can go upto 10,000+. Any suggestions on implementation, or any design flaw if any in current implementation, or any suggestions really appreciated.

I have written another implementation for the same and this time I have used Hangfire to check for db records every 1 minute. This seems to have an issue too works well in IIS but not in Azure. Implementation is as follows

```
List data = getfromdb();
writelog()
foreach(var d in data )
{
 if(checklogic)
  {
    pushtoquartz(d)
  }
}
```

Have handled Exceptions.

Thanks for reading through. First time on on stackoverflow, I can add more info if necessary that I missed.

Environment:

- Dotnetcore   v3.1
- Azure App Service Linux B1-Tier

Comment: @davidfowl any suggestions.